# Informix - select from a temp table created in a 4gl with Interactive debugger?

Tags: sql, informix

Got a lot of 4gl to debug lately, most of which use lots of temp tables.  Using the "interactive" debugger, I can break after the insert into tmp_table.  And I would like to do a select * query on that tmp_table, is that possible in the interactive debugger?

Or how to do it on a 3rd party sql client?  A simple
**select * from tmp_table**
would result in *Error: The specified table (tmp_table) is not in the database. (State:S0002, Native Code: FFFFFF32)*

Comment: Temporary tables are private to a session; you'd have to do it from the debugger, using the debugger.  Offhand, I'm not sure if there's a clean way to do it.  `FUNCTION select_from_tmptable() DEFINE t RECORD LIKE TmpTable_Template.*; DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM TmpTable; FOREACH c INTO t.* DISPLAY t.* END FOREACH END FUNCTION` might be the best way to do it -- but you'd have to compile that into the program. Note that for the DEFINE to work, there would have to be a table with the correct structure (hence the name including _template_).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I think this is a good answer, and it tells me about the **display** function, a good old **println**.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, is there a limit on DISPLAY?  If I concat ("||") more than few variables into a single variable, and then display that single variable, sometimes I get empty line.  Is there a special trick or sth?

Comment: The `||` concatenation operator returns NULL if either of its operands is NULL.  The comma concatenation operator handles NULL with ore aplomb; it treats it as an empty string.  Is that any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a similar approach to what Jonathan describes, at a previous workplace, we had a library function with a name similar to  `FUNCTION dump_temp_table(tablename)` that took as an argument a tablename and unloaded that table to the file tablename.unl.  You simply called that function from the debugger using the call command passing the tablename you were interested in as an argument

Using Genero I was quickly able to recreate with the following ...

```
FUNCTION dump_temp_table(tablename)
DEFINE tablename STRING
DEFINE filename STRING
DEFINE sql STRING

   LET sql = SFMT("SELECT * FROM %1",tablename)
   LET filename = SFMT("%1.unl", tablename)
   UNLOAD TO filename sql
END FUNCTION
```

... if using 4gl you should be able to come up with something similar (replacing the modernized Genero syntax such as STRING and SFMT with CHAR etc)

Comment: Thanks fourjs for the alternative suggestion, what's SFMT in Genero?

Comment: For SFMT, http://www.4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/#c_fgl_operators_SFMT.html  If you are ever interested, read from pages such as http://www.4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/#c_fgl_nf.html to see how we have modernized Informix 4gl over the years

Comment: I probably should have used `LET sql = "SELECT * FROM ", tablename` or `LET sql = "SELECT * FROM " || tablename`  to avoid confusion.  I've got in the habit of using SFMT, avoids issues with NULLs and commas etc